# Can't boot from Windows 10 USB while HDD attached

Tags: windows-10

When I attempt to boot from Windows USB when HDD is connected, it gets stuck at the first rotating dots animation forever.

When I disconnect the HDD, exact same steps lead to successful boot from USB. I can successfully boot from a Linux USB, regardless whether or not the HDD is connected. The Windows USB I'm using also does not have any issues with booting on other computers. I did try different USB memory sticks.

The HDD seems to have some damage - SMART data is all green (all values larger than thresholds), but drive self test (DST) fails. Windows that is currently installed on the HDD fails to boot: goes into automatic repair and then crashes with blue screen of death "DRIVER PNP WATCHDOG". I can access files on the HDD using a Linux live USB without issues.

What could cause this? Is there any way to run windows reset or reinstall on the HDD?

Comment: When you are trying to boot from the HDD, have you unplugged all the USB devices? If you haven't, try rebooting when they are all unplugged.

Comment: yes, the live usb was the only connected usb device

Comment: Have you tried booting from the HDD without connecting the live usb? This might solve the problem.